# Create data for Image column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, types

I need to create data to test the limit of Image Datatype in SQL Server. It is able to hold variable-length binary data from 0 through 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) bytes. I am using the following directly in SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO Employees (Id, Name, Photo) 
SELECT 10, 'John', BulkColumn FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'E:\photo.jpeg', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture
```

My question is, how do I ensure that the max size (2,147,483,647 bytes) is being inserted into the column? Do I just find an image of size 2G and insert it into the column? Is there another way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you doubt that it cannot hold the defined size? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424.aspx

Comment: ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. You should use varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: @MitchWheat This is part of boundary testing requirement.

Comment: @bummi We are aware that this will be removed in future version but it is one of the requirement for testing.

Comment: @plasticdoor66: I would assume that Microsoft would not say 2GB-1 in their documentation if it did not work. What you propose is to test  SQL Server, not your code or processes. This is not a useful or realistic check

Comment: @gbn - I was struggling to work out how to phrase exactly this. I suppose after the size checks, the OP can move on to checking that *every* valid file of up to 2GB can be accommodated in this column, which will take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Most JPEG viewers completely ignore the bytes after the image data.  The following code will tack on enough bytes to make the file whatever size you want.  I tested it and the resulting image opened in the Windows image viewer, paint.net, and Photoshop.  You should be able to create test files with it...

```
    long desiredSize = 200000;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
    string filename = @"c:\temp\sample.jpg";
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        fs.Seek(desiredSize - fs.Length - 1, SeekOrigin.End);
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, 1);
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Comment: @plasticdoor - Did this work for you?  If not, can you provide additional info?